# Setting up monitor hz to 144 through xrandr makes my monitor cut off half of screen

Tags: linux, fedora, x11, i3, xrandr

Here is how it looks. On bottom of the pic is part of the terminal. This happens when i exec `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 -r 144`[image] This is my modes [image] I also tried to exec `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 -r 144` before i3 starts in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` file, but it seems doesn't work. [image]

How can i fix that? My system. Fedora i3 Spin distro
[image]

Comment: does it work at 120 Hz? 60 Hz? This might simply be your screen not being able to work at full data rate, maybe due to overselling its abilities (screen firmware is *the worst*) or through that high rate being problematic with the signal quality caused by your HDMI output + cable. (If it works at 120 Hz: that's an excellent refresh rate; it's already physiologically heavily contested by the people actually doing proper studies on that whether refresh rates higher than 60 fps have any provable influence on human perception / performance, and the difference between 120 and 144 Hz doesn't exist.)

Comment: (oh and TFT screens actually don't have refresh rates, as their pixels don't "turn off" or fade out as they did in CRTs; things are a lot better now!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller it works good with 60 hz, with 120 it's like 2/3 of screen is black. My monitor works with 144 hz in windows

Comment: what is important information! Please edit your question to include it!